# What is the Difference Between These two jQuery Code Snippets?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm rather new to jQuery and I came across something. What is the difference between these code snippets? I think they'll do exactly the same thing.

```js
$("p.expendable").on('mouseover', function(){
  $(this).remove();
});

$('p').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('p.expendable').remove();
});
```

Comment: I have no idea what youre trying to do. OnMouseOver => remove myself?

Comment: Both are different!

Comment: the question is, which code is correct

Comment: I'm trying to remove a paragraph

Comment: they totally don't do the same thing. The first one removes a `p` that has the class `expendable` when hovered. The second will remove all `p` with class `expendable` of the page when any `p` is hovered

Comment: thx @Kaddath thats what i wanted to hear

Comment: The first one binds a mouseover to paragraphs with the specific class you want to remove. The second binds a mouseover to every paragraph. Unless you have a reason to use the second, the first is likely more performant.

Comment: you are putting an on-mouse-over trigger on different elements, it's not a matter of which is cleaner, it's a matter of where you want the event to trigger.

Comment: hehe wow!! you really stirred the hornet's nest on this one. hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different.

Considering the first case , if the current hovered `p` element have `expendable` class then it will remove that specific element.

```js
$("p.expendable").on('mouseover', function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="expendable"> Testing</p>
<p> Testing 2</p>
<p> Testing 3</p>
```

In second case the currently hovered element is any `p` tag irrespective of whether it have any class or not, then it will remove all `p` element which have 'expendable' class

```js
$('p').on('mouseover', function() {
  $('p.expendable').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="expendable"> Testing</p>
<p> Testing 2</p>
<p> Testing 3</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

delegate is cleaner:

```
$(document).delegate("p.expendable", 'mouseover', function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

It says, if `p.expendable` is created, attach function to it that deletes itself. (deprecated!) Good catch on this one @[epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello)

Use:

```
$(document).on("p.expendable", 'mouseover', function(){
       $(this).remove();
    });
```

or just:

```
$("p.expendable").on('mouseover', function(){
           $(this).remove();
        });
```

Comment: If you want only the paragraphs in a specific element to have said functionality, make sure you change out the document to the parent element you need.

Comment: Yes using deprecated methods is always cleaner... lol This does not answer the question either.

Comment: Ah my bad, didnt see that. Good catch. was using delegate way back, didnt realize it was deprecated.